Spring Boot @Async Method Prevents JPA INSERT Queries from Executing with Multiple Database Connections
I'm working on a Spring Boot application that connects to multiple databases using Spring Data JPA. I have a method that saves an entity to one of the databases. The method functions correctly when it is synchronous, and the save() operation executes as expected. However, when I annotate the method with @Async, the INSERT query no longer executes, while the SELECT queries continue to work fine. It's worth noting that the @Async annotation works without issues when the application is connected to a single database.
What I've Tried:

Ensured proper transaction management: The method is annotated with @Transactional.
Checked for read-only transactions: Verified that the transaction is not marked as read-only.
Verified entity state: Ensured that the entity is new and should trigger an INSERT.
Manually flushed the EntityManager: When I tried to use entityManager.flush(), I encountered the following error:
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: no transaction is in progress
Reviewed SQL logs: Enabled SQL logging, but the INSERT query isn’t even being generated when the method is async.
Checked for any exceptions: There are no other exceptions being thrown.

@Async("asyncTaskExecutor")
@EventListener
public void eventHandler(Event log) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    eventLogWsRepo.save(log);
    eventLogWsRepo.flush();
    log.info("Event Log save successful");
}

@EnableAsync
@Configuration
public class AsyncConfiguration {

    @Bean("asyncTaskExecutor")
    public Executor asyncTaskExecutor(){
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(4);
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(150);
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(4);
        taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("AsyncTaskThread - ");
        taskExecutor.initialize();
        return taskExecutor;
    }
}


Instead of using an async method why can’t you direct submit the saving task in the ExecutorService. ?

Which method has the @Transactional annotation?

I used @Transactional for the event handler method and also tried wrapping the save task in another method with the same annotation, but that didn’t work for me either, so I removed it from the method
